# Will ddrescue make recovering an overwritten partition easier?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk, ddrescue

I have an external HDD that's been erroneously formatted. I've never used `ddrescue` before, and have read much about it. The one thing I'm a little confused about is: Will creating an image of the HDD w/ `ddrescue` and using `testdisk` on it be any better than using `testdisk` directly on the drive—assuming tha the drive is not in use?

I am under the impression that an image created by `ddrescue` is somehow more thorough than the drive itself (and can thus be larger than the maximum storage capacity of the drive). The more I learn about `ddrescue`, the less I believe this, but I'm still not sure.

Is this a false impression?

Comment: Yes;  That is a false impression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will `ddrescue` make recovering an overwritten partition easier?

It will be "easier" only if the original drive is faulty, otherwise the difficulty won't change. `ddrescue` ensures that all of the readable data is copied on the bitstream copy (image drive).

Recovery tools might freeze or crash while working on a damaged drive, hence working on a copy which "hides" the I/O errors (basically because the failing sectors have been replaced by zeros) is strongly advised.

> Will creating an image of the HDD w/ `ddrescue` and using `testdisk` on it **be any better** than using `testdisk` directly

Yes, it can be better. Not in the sense of easiness, but in the sense of safety. Keep in mind that `testdisk` is a data recovery program that may be used to **write new (partition) information** on the drive. When you are performing data recovery you will likely not want to write anything on it.

This is because you might realize later that the old information was more useful than the one you wrote (maybe erroneusly). Instead, if you mess up with the copy, it's no big deal.

Use `testdisk` on the original drive only for trivial matters (e.g. you overwrote the partition table but each file system is still intact) or ensure the drive is write-blocked.

> I am under the impression that an image created by `ddrescue` is somehow more thorough than the drive itself

This is not true. The copy is an exact replica on what is on the drive, minus the possible I/O errors encountered while copying faulty drives.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good general practice to make backup before you mess with the drive. I understand you do not suspect your drive to be faulty, so it is not really important whether you work with it or with its image. Still, working with one and not touching the other has one big advantage (over working without backup): if something goes wrong you will have an intact copy to duplicate (filesystems with copy-on-write rock!) and start over (with another tool maybe).

As for your impression: I agree with Ramhound, it is false.